# Javascript Regex: How to bold specific words with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Given a needle and a haystack... I want to put bold tags around the needle. So what regex expression would I use with replace()? I want SPACE to be the delimeter and I want the search to be case insensitive

so say the needle is "cow" and the haystack is

```
cows at www.cows.com, milk some COWS
```

would turn into

```
<b>cows</b> at www.cows.com, milk some <b>COWS</b>
```

also keywords should be able to have spaces in it so if the keyword is "who is mgmt"...

```
great band. who is mgmt btw?
```

would turn into

```
great band. <b>who is mgmt</b> btw?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a regex to do what you're looking for:

```
(^|\s)(cows)(\s|$)
```

In JS, replacement is like so:

```
myString.replace(/(^|\s)(cows)(\s|$)/ig, '$1<b>$2</b>$3');
```

Wrapped up neatly in a reusable function:

```
function updateHaystack(input, needle) {
    return input.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\s)(' + needle + ')(\\s|$)','ig'), '$1<b>$2</b>$3');
}

var markup = document.getElementById('somediv').innerHTML;
var output = updateHaystack(markup, 'cows');
document.getElementById('somediv').innerHTML = output;
```

Comment: is there a typo?

function boldKeywords(keywords, haystack) {
 for (var c = 0; c < keywords.length; c++) {
  haystack = haystack.replace(new RegExp('(^|\s)(' + keywords[c] + ')(\s|$)','ig'), '$1<b>$2</b>$3');
 }
 return haystack;
}



for some reason that code doesn't bold anything. thanks

Comment: updateHaystack('cows at www.cows.com, milk some COWS', 'cows'); doesn't bold anything, but updateHaystack('cows at www.cows.com, milk some COWS', 'cow'); changes cows to <b>cow</b>s

Comment: @inktri good spot. Of course 'cow'/'cows' is an example here. I did not escape my \s - that's fixed.

Answer (score 12):

For those who don't want SPACE as the delimiter, simply don't use `\s`.

```
function updateHaystack(input, needle) 
{
 return input.replace(new RegExp('(^|)(' + needle + ')(|$)','ig'), '$1<b>$2</b>$3');
}
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
findstring: /(^|\s)(cows)(\s|$)/ig
newstring: '$1<b>$2</b>$3'
```

The \b markers are for "word boundaries"; the /ig flags are for case-ignoring and global matching, respectively.

The usage of the () captures and then $1/$2/$3 in the new string text is so that the capitalization and spacing of whatever was matched will be preserved.

Answer (score -1):

```
var needle = 'cows';

var regexp = new RegExp('(^|\s)('+needle+')(\s|$)', 'ig');

var old_string = 'cows at www.cows.com, milk some COWs';

var new_string = old_string.replace(regexp, '<b>$1$2$3</b>');
```

Comment: Your example won't work, because it requires a space to both precede and follow the needle, which isn't the case for any of the instances of 'cows' in your old_string.

Comment: He said he wanted space as the delimiter. To make it work with start and end of strings it could be '(^|\s)'+needle+'(\s|$)' not tested but I think that should work