# Javascript Regex: Bolding needles in a haystack

Tags: javascript, regex

#### Related (but not the same):

> [Javascript Regex: How to bold specific words with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230445/javascript-regex-how-to-bold-specific-words-with-regex)

Given a needle and a haystack... I want to put bold tags around the needle. So what regex expression would I use with replace()? I want SPACE to be the delimeter and I want the search to be case insensitive and I want special characters (such as @!#.()) to be ignored in the search

so say the needle is "cow" and the haystack is

```
cows, at www.cows.com, milk some COWS!
```

would turn into

```
<b>cows</b>, at www.cows.com, milk some <b>COWS</b>!
```

also keywords should be able to have spaces in it so if the keyword is "who is mgmt"...

```
great band. who. is. mgmt btw?
```

would turn into

```
great band. <b>who. is. mgmt</b> btw?
```

I've got this currently:

```
function updateHaystack(input, needle) {
    return input.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\s)(' + needle + ')(\\s|$)','ig'), '$1<b>$2</b>$3');
}
```

unfortunately it doesn't bold words that are concatenated with a special char... eg. !cow does not turn into `!<b>cow</b>`

Thank you

Comment: Why are you continuously reposting this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243321/javascript-regex-add-bold-tags-around-needles-in-a-haystack

Comment: What are you doing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230445/javascript-regex-how-to-bold-specific-words-with-regex

Comment: because i've altered the question

Comment: inktri.  You need to stop re-posting the same question.  You asked it here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230445) two days ago, got a good answer AND marked it as accepted.  If you have a sublety or nuance you are trying to get clarification on, describe it as such.  Otherwise, your questions will continue to be down-voted and closed.

Comment: i just realized the examples are wrong... and i've altered the question as such. what am i supposed to do? just edit the original question? or do i repost it with the altered examples, etc. ?

Comment: when you post a new question related to a previous one, do two things: 1. Provide a link to the original question. 2. Be clear and explicit about the ways in which this new question is different.

Comment: Or just ask in the comments of the original thread for a little additional help.  Honestly, you're just copying and pasting the same text for all of these questions.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `\b` should do what you want. It's a zero-width match of "word boundaries".

```
function updateHaystack(input, needle) {
    return input.replace(new RegExp('\\b(' + needle + ')\\b','ig'), '<b>$1</b>');
}
```

Comment: Why `new RegExp()` instead of literal regex syntax?

Comment: The snippet is based on the snippet in the question. I only made changes necessary to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow punctuation to be part of the needle, just add it:

```
function updateHaystack(input, needle) {
    return input.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\s)(' + needle + '[!.,?]?)(\\s|$)','ig'), '$1<b>$2</b>$3');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Allow any non-whitespace character to be part of the needle:

```
"cows, at www.cows.com, milk COWS!".replace(/(\s|^)(cow\S*)(\s|$)/ig, '$1<b>$2</b>$3');
// Will return: "<b>cows,</b> at www.cows.com, milk <b>COWS!</b>"
```

Comment: I believe the `^` in `(^|\b)` is redundant - the start of the string is a word boundary.

Comment: Hmmm... I was thinking `/\b(cow\S*)\b/ig` to account for strings like `'(cows)'`.

Comment: Nah, thinking about it this would break at the closing paren. Your's is better.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to put an optional section for the special char in the regex:

```
'(^|\\s)(' + needle + '[@!#.(),?]*)(\\s|$)'
```