# Javascript Regex: Bolding needles in a haystack edit

Tags: javascript, regex

**This is a slightly modified version of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247636/javascript-regex-bolding-needles-in-a-haystack). The difference is I don't the special characters to be included in the bold tags if they are on front or back.**

Given a needle and a haystack... I want to put bold tags around the needle. So what regex expression would I use with replace()? I want SPACE to be the delimeter and I want the search to be case insensitive and I want special characters (such as @!#.()) to be ignored in the search

so say the needle is "cow" and the haystack is

```
cows, at www.cows.com, milk some COWS!
```

would turn into

```
<b>cows</b>, at www.cows.com, milk some <b>COWS</b>!
```

also keywords should be able to have spaces in it so if the keyword is "who is mgmt"...

```
great band. who. is. mgmt btw?
```

would turn into

```
great band. <b>who. is. mgmt</b> btw?
```

Note the dots in the above

I've got this currently:

```
function updateHaystack(input, needle) {
    return input.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\s)(' + needle + ')(\\s|$)','ig'), '$1<b>$2</b>$3');
}
```

unfortunately it doesn't bold words that are concatenated with a special char... eg. !cow does not turn into `!<b>cow</b>`

Answer (score 0):

Just create a class containing your special characters before and after the `needle`:

```
function updateHaystack(input, needle) {
  var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s|[!@#,])(' + needle + ')([!@#,]|\\s|$)','ig');
  return input.replace(re, '$1<b>$2</b>$3');
}
```

Notice, however, that if you add the dot (`.`) to that list, you'll end up matching things like "www.cows.com". If you don't want that to happen, you should narrow your question.

Also, you should escape the `needle` if it contains characters that have a meaning in the RegExp, such as the dot `(.)` or asterisk `(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe regular expressions are not what you need. If you seek pattern matching where the patterns themselves (the "cow") are not regular expressions on their own, try using a pattern matching algorithm.

You can use [KMP (Knuth-Moriss-Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) if you only have one pattern to find ([implementation example](http://www.unarmedjavascript.com/2008/09/05/knuth-morris-pratt-example/) curtusy of Google) or [AC (Aho-Corasick)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho-Corasick_algorithm) if you have more than one pattern to find at the same time and want to be extremely efficient (otherwise you can just run KMP several times).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
function boldNeedle(needle, haystack) {
    var regex = RegExp("\\b(" + needle.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.\\^$|,#\s]/g, "\\$&") + ")\\b", "gi");
    return haystack.replace(regex, "<strong>$1</strong>");
};

boldNeedle("foo", "blah blah FOO blah foo blah")
===
"blah blah <strong>FOO</strong> blah <strong>foo</strong> blah"
```

**Edit**: I should explain how this is different from the other solution: It escapes the needle so no part of it is treated as a regular expression.

Comment: What if the word foo was part of another word, and you wanted that to be bolded?