# Make single character css styled site wide?

Tags: html, css

Client has asked for just the `/` of his site to be red... Throughout the entire site!

Do I have to add spans around each /, or is there an easier way?

Comment: Not with CSS, but it's possible with javascript

Comment: I would go with the `<span>`, if you have to parse the whole site for this tag and change it, that could be bad and slow.

Comment: Why on earth would you want that? Is there a real reason or is it just a whimsy of the client? If it's the latter, explain why it adds no real meaning and is going to take long time to do it.

Comment: This either adds markup (could be a fair bit depending on the number of characters that need adjusting) or js overhead to the site. Either way the gain isn't going to be worth the performance hit. I swear the faster the internet gets the dumber things the clients ask for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this sample helps. I found it in SO. You can replace the `&reg;` with the html code of slash `&#47;`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('*').each(function() {
        var n = $(this).html().replace(
            new RegExp('®','g'),
            '<sup>®</sup>'
            ).replace(
            new RegExp('&reg;','g'),
            '<sup>&reg;</sup>'
            );
        $(this).html(n);
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SowmyaShivaram/Fwjd4/21/)

Comment: this replaces different character.. if you run this with slash, it will replace all the slashes (eg. in <a href="www.sample.com/index">, etc.)

Comment: it can be done with adding space after & before the slash like &nbsp;&#47;&nbsp

Comment: if all the slashes in the site match `\s\/\s` (rather than `&nbsp;`) then this could work..

Answer (score 2):

You could try following jQuery script:

```
$('body').html($('body').html()
          .replace(/\/(?=[^>]*<)/gi, '<span style="color:red">/</span>'));​​​​
```

It simply wraps all slashes that are not inside tags with span.

Check how fast it is for your site, I believe it could be usable.

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vagvL/) to demonstrate that using the lookahead `(?=[^>]*<)` is important to prevent matches inside tags `<>` to be replaced. Try removing it and resulting HTML will be broken.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done with css alone. Check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230445/javascript-regex-how-to-bold-specific-words-with-regex) for how to do it with javascript

Answer (score -1):

You have to wrap each occurrence of the character inside `span` markup or other suitable markup. (Actually, `<font color=red>/</font>` would work, too.) You can however do this dynamically client-side, if this sounds more suitable (you would have client-side JavaScript that traverses the document tree and does the wrapping).

Note: This won’t apply to content in elements that have plain text as declared content, such as `option` elements. Inside them, individual characters cannot be styled differently from other content of the element.

Comment: aren't `font` tags deprecated? If he's gonna use inline styles he should use `<span style="color:red;">/</span>` but personally I would add a class to the span - what if the client comes back and asks for all slashes to be 13px, he'd need to do it all again so atleast once it's done once it's easy to change

Comment: Various documents may declare `font` deprecated, obsolete or whatever; I was just pointing out that it works, and so does e.g. `<a class=slash>/</a>` with suitable CSS code. If the point is to change the visual rendering of some characters for an unspecified reason, `font` would convey the idea best, and you can always use `class` with it, too, with or without a `color` attribute.

Comment: -1 font tags are deprecated. They also don't function properly in some cases, because they are deprecated.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks, there is no factual evidence for the claim “They also don't function properly in some cases, because they are deprecated.” They actually work a bit *more often* than CSS counterparts (namely when CSS support is disabled or your CSS is overridden).