# What is the easiest way to bold one word that appears many times across my website?

Tags: html, css, formatting

In my website I have a particular word which appears on many of my pages and want every single one to be stylised to be bold. Is there a way to do this via CSS or will I have to add code to every single page?

Comment: Could you use JavaScript? or just CSS?

Comment: no way to tell really; no code and which element tag are you using for it and if there's an id/class assigned to it

Comment: There is no id/class assigned to the word itself, but there are a few id/class tags that encompass that specific word across the website

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230445/javascript-regex-how-to-bold-specific-words-with-regex

Comment: `<div class="shared-class"></div>` `.shared-class{ font-weight: bold;}` As easy as that...

Comment: But that would bold out everything within the class, whereas I just want ONE word within the class to be bold... :/ @badjuju

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to do this with CSS, without adding markup to every occurrence of the word.

You can use a combination of CSS/JQuery to do it like this:

CSS:

```
.word {
   font-weight: bold;
 }
```

JS:

`$('html').text().replace(/word/g,"<span class='word'>$1</span>");`